# Minimum number of lines to connet points

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a set of points A[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...(xn,yn)]. I have to draw lines to connect these points based on a given condition. There is atleast one line which connects them. Suppose this line starts at (x1,y1). Now if (y2-y1)<=(x2-x1) and also x2!=x1. then I can draw a line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). If not then I will have to start a new line from point (x2,y2). Now the next point i.e. (x3,y3) can be connected to line from (x1,y1) or to line from (x2,y2) only if the same condition is satisfied. It is possible that (x3.y3) can connect to both (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Our goal is to connect all points using minimum number of lines. So it is possible that if we connect (x3,y3) to (x1,y1) then for next point (x4,y4) may be connecting (x3,y3) does not satisfy condition and connecting (x2,y2) also does not satisfy so we need to start new line to answer becomes 3. But if we would have connected (x3,y3) to (x2,y2) and then (x4,y4) can be connected to (x1,y1) then only 2 lines are needed so answer is 2.

So I want efficient way to find minimum number of lines connecting these points.

for eg: A{(1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(5,1)}

Start from (1,1)

(3-1) is not less than (2-1)(condition : y2-y1<=x2-x1) so we will have to start a new line from (2,3).

So Lines{(1,1),(2,3)}

Now (3,1) can only be connected to (1,1). So start point for (1,1) changes to (3,1)

So Lines{(3,1),(2,3)}

Finally (5,1) can also be connected to (3,1).

So final answer is 2 lines are needed to connect these points.

Currently I am using backtracking but my solution is getting timed out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Your question is not clear, as well as the way to explain the example. Do you consider the line passing through (1,1), (2,1) and (5,1) as a single line or as two lines ? The points are aligned, so it is a single line from a geometry stand point.

Comment: Line does not necessarily have to be a straight line. By line I mean anything that connects a set of points that satisfy a given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your ordering restriction is

```
y2 - y1 <= x2 - x1
```

Use a little algebra to rearrange terms:

```
y2 - x2 <= y1 - x1
```

From here, the logic is simple.  Compute [y-x] for each point.  Sort the points on that value.  You now have the sequence to draw one line through all of the points.

Comment: I don't want one line passing through all points, I want minimum number of lines without changing position of points.

Comment: You said "Line does not necessarily have to be a straight line. By line I mean anything that connects a set of points that satisfy a given condition."  What I describe above shows you how to take the points in order, drawing one line to connect them all, obeying the given condition.  You start at teh point with the greatest `x-y` value.